# Understanding GROUP BY with a LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a simple SQL query to give me information about all of the users who have commented on an image like this...

```
SELECT user.id, user.userName, user.displayName, user.currentDefault, user.discipline
FROM user 
INNER JOIN imageComment ON user.id = imageComment.commentAuthorId
WHERE imageComment.imageAlbumJunctionId = 37 
GROUP BY user.id  
LIMIT 2
```

I have the `LIMIT 2` on there because I know there are only two comments for this image. And I have the `GROUP BY user.id` on there because I only want to show information about a user once, even if they comment multiple times.

So lets say that "Mike" commented on a photo twice. My question is, does this query...

1. Only search for 2 comments because of the `LIMIT`, and then perform the `GROUP BY user.id`
2. Perform the `GROUP BY user.id` and then search the full table for a second unique user

I am hoping that this query does #1 because if it does #2 that would cause it to search the entire table looking for a second user when "Mike" was actually the one that did both comments. And I did try an `EXPLAIN` but I don't really understand it because it gives the same output whether there is a `GROUP BY` or `LIMIT`. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query finds the first two users who have commented an Image, so it's #2.

I'd suggest:

```
select ...
from user 
where exists 
(
  select * from imageComment 
  where imageComment.commentAuthorId = user.id 
  and imageComment.imageAlbumJunctionId = 37
)
```

where exists is faster than a inner join because it can stop after the first. Good indices should be set.

Comment: Led me to do some reading on WHERE EXISTS. Thank you for the extra bonus. Didn't know about it's benefits until now.

Answer (score 0):

`LIMIT` is applied after the `GROUP BY user.id`. So in this case, #2 is happening. But the `WHERE` clause will filter the table first, so it's not searching the whole table. Your query will give you correct results, but I think this should be better:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user.id, user.userName, user.displayName, user.currentDefault, user.discipline
FROM user 
INNER JOIN imageComment ON user.id = imageComment.commentAuthorId
WHERE imageComment.imageAlbumJunctionId = 37 
LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample Tables

```
User Table                          imageComment Table
id  | userName                      id | commentAuthorId | imageAlbumJunctionId
---------------                     -------------------------------------------
 1  | Mike                           1 | 1               | 37
 2  | John                           2 | 1               | 37
 3  | Carla                          3 | 2               | 37
                                     4 | 3               | 37
```

Split explanation  about what going on

```
SELECT user.id, user.userName
FROM user 
INNER JOIN imageComment ON user.id = imageComment.commentAuthorId
WHERE imageComment.imageAlbumJunctionId = 37
```

this will return

```
 1  | Mike 
 1  | Mike 
 2  | John
 3  | Carla
```

after your `GROUP BY user.id` you will now get

```
 1  | Mike 
 2  | John
 3  | Carla
```

now we  use the `LIMIT 2` and get

```
 1  | Mike 
 2  | John
```